# Convert if ((loc = [player locateCardValue:8]) > - 1) to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, code-conversion

How would you convert this Objective-C

```
if ((loc = [player locateCardValue:8]) > -1) {
```

to Swift 3?

`[player locateCardValue]` returns an integer of the location where the card `'8'` was found.  Returning `-1` means it didn't find the card `'8'`.

I could  use ...

```
let loc = player.locateCard(withValue: 8)
if loc > -1 {
```

but I have multiple nesting of IF's and it would get really messy.

Comment: Both the Swift and the Objective-C version have an `if`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to convert `locateCardValue` to return an Optional `Int?`. Then you could simply do

```
if let loc = player.locateCard(withValue: 8) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you could use a switch statement

```
switch player.locateCard(withValue: 8) {
case -1: print("No card.")
case 1: // ...
// etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I got hung up on keeping the -1 return value.  Optional value works as well.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the best approach is not to convert it "as is", but to make it more Swift-like.

In this case I think I would change the `locateCard` to return an `Optional<Int>` and return `nil` when the card is not found.

```
func locateCard(withValue: Int) -> Card? {
    // return the position if found, nil otherwise
}
```

Then, you can just write

```
if let card = player.locateCard(withValue: 8) {

}
```

Comment: For the protocol: The Objective-C piece of code isn't Objective-C'ish.

Comment: How does reduce the number of nested `if`?